# Why does Vim add additional length to octal number when decrementing?

Tags: number-formatting

If I decrement my octal number so that it wraps around Vim adds length to this number.
**Can the length added be configured?**
Example:
`00`
Decrement with `Ctrl-X` gives

`01777777777777777777777`

Even if I have a octal byte
`000000000`
it gets lengthened to
`01777777777777777777777`
event though I think it should still be the *same* byte length after wrapping.

Eg.
`01777777`

Answer (score 5):

### Solution

(only for decimal, not for octal)

You can simply add `unsigned` to your `nrformat`:

```
:set nrformats+=unsigned
```

See `:help nrformats` for more info

### Explanation

Because your **Vim** uses **64bit**.

The highest values you can store in `64-bit`:

---

In `decimal` it is `2^64 - 1` or:

```
18446744073709551615
```

If you convert this now to `octal`, it's this:

```
01777777777777777777777
```

And for `binary`:

```
0b1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

---

---

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?
I would class this as a bug as it changes the length of the number being edited in a non-predictable way.

Comment: I am currently in a restaurant, as soon as I am home I am gonna extend my question and put some resources. And yes that is unexpected behaviour, but also expected and sertainly not a Bug:)

Comment: @GustavBlomqvist Okay I have **updated** my answer and **found** a `solution`. That at least works for `decimal` :)

Comment: Hey, would you mind to accept my answer? I really want that `15 points` :')